# Rails 5.1 radio_button_tag prevents buttons from being clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have a User model. Each User `has_one` Package.

On the User form, I render the Package choices as radio buttons with this:

```
  <% Package.all.each do |p| %>
    <div class="switch-field">
      <%= radio_button_tag('package[id]', p.id) %>
      <%= label_tag("package_#{p.id}", number_to_currency(p.price)) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But the buttons cannot be clicked. If I change the tag line to this -
 removing the [id]:

```
  <% Package.all.each do |p| %>
    <div class="switch-field">
      <%= radio_button_tag('package', p.id) %>
      <%= label_tag("package_#{p.id}", number_to_currency(p.price)) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

then they can be clicked.

However this submits to the controller as "package"=>"1" whereas the first example submits as a nested object inside user, like this:

```
"user"=>{..user field.., "package"=>{"id"=>"6"}}
```

I would expect this to be the Rails way to submit the data (with the controller having this:

```
wrap_parameters :user, include: [:event, :package]
```

So how can I get the radio buttons to work using "package[id]" as the name for the group?

Comment: Are you using `fields_for` in the form?

Comment: @Pavan no I'm not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is just a mismatch between what the generated id of the `radio_button_tag` and what you pass into the `label_tag`. You have a couple of options to fix this.

#### Option 1 - Quick fix

Viewing the html of the page using your code, the radio button has an id of `"package_id_0"`, not `"package_0"`, so we just need to update the `label_tag` like this:

```
<% 3.times do |x| %>
  <div class="switch-field">
    <%= radio_button_tag('package[id]', x) %>
    <%= label_tag("package_id_#{x}", number_to_currency(x * 1.50)) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### Option 2 - Update the radio button

If you want `"package_0"` instead of `"package_id_0"` you can pass it into the `radio_button_tag`

```
<% 3.times do |x| %>
  <div class="switch-field">
    <%= radio_button_tag('package[id]', x, false, id: "package_#{x}") %>
    <%= label_tag("package_#{x}", number_to_currency(x * 1.50)) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### Option 3 - use the block label tag

I prefer to do things this way as it's more tolerant of hitting whitespace around the label and generally provides a larger 'hit box'. I add a span with a class around the text in case there's any need for styling.

```
<% 3.times do |x| %>
  <div class="switch-field">
    <%= label_tag do %>
      <%= radio_button_tag('package[id]', x) %>
      <%= content_tag(:span, number_to_currency(x * 1.50), class: 'label') %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```